# uninitialized constant in Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

In worker appeared error `NameError: uninitialized constant DeliveryWorker`. error in the **sidekiq logs**.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant DeliveryWorker
2018-04-27T07:39:47.163Z 8323 TID-1uztxc WARN: /home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/sidekiq-3.5.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:46:in `process'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:28:in `public_send'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:28:in `dispatch'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/call/async.rb:7:in `dispatch'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:50:in `block in dispatch'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:76:in `block in task'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:339:in `block in task'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/task.rb:44:in `block in initialize'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/celluloid-0.17.3/lib/celluloid/task/fibered.rb:14:in `block in create'
```

In controller is called `DeliveryWorker.perform_async(@invoice.id)`
File **delivery_worker.rb** is located in the **app/workers** folder.

`puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` returns `app/workers`.
I rebooted sidekiq.
There are no errors in naming.

**delivery_worker.rb**

```
class DeliveryWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(bill_id)
    DeliveryService.new(bill_id).call
  end
end
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Where does the error happen? In the controller? Rebooting Sidekiq cannot be of any help since it’s Rails issue, not Sidekiq.

Comment: sorry, not specify. error in the sidekiq logs

Comment: So is it the the sidekiq jobs or the application (controller) logs?

Comment: error in the **sidekiq logs**, but in controller I called `DeliveryWorker.perform_async(@invoice.id)`

Comment: How do you start sidekiq?

Comment: `bundle exec sidekiq -e production -P /home/evans/www/evans/current/apps/www/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid -L /home/evans/www/evans/shared/log/sidekiq.log --daemon`

Comment: Can we see your DeliveryWorker class code?

Comment: added in body question

Comment: @evans ist in specific folder app/workers/somefoled/file.rb ?

Comment: In `DeliveryService` just logic

Comment: @7urkm3n no, app/workers/delivery_worker.rb

Comment: @mudasobwa "Rebooting Sidekiq cannot be of any help since it’s Rails issue, not Sidekiq." - except it can totally help. IIRC, sidekiq in development mode does not watch the code files and reload changed classes or pick up new ones. If this class was added after sidekiq was launched, its restart is likely necessary. But from comments above, they seem to have this problem in production, so I guess this hypothesis is not applicable here.

Comment: Is the worker in your `eager_load_paths` (not only the `autoload_paths`)?

Comment: @ndn how to see?

Comment: `_YourAppModule_::Application.config.eager_load_paths`. `_YourAppModule_` should be defined in `application.rb`.

Comment: **app/workers** folder is available in `eager_load_paths`